# Unable to upload an DataFrame containing mixed-typed data with DolphinDB Python API

Tags: python, pandas, dolphindb

I tried to upload a DataFrame with DolphinDB Python API. It contained a column with mixed types.

```
import dolphindb as ddb
import pandas as pd

sess = ddb.session('localhost', 8848)
df = DataFrame({'a': [1, 1.0, 'a']})
sess.upload({'df': df})
```

Then I got the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File "/home/ynwang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dolphindb/session.py", line 64, in upload
>
> return self.cpp.upload(nameObjectDict)
>
> RuntimeError:  in upload: Failed to read response header from the socket with IO error type 1

And the session just disconnected. I would like to know why this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Try to first initialize an empty session and then connect to localhost session :

```
import dolphindb as ddb
import pandas as pd

conn=ddb.session()
conn.connect( 'localhost', 8848)
df = DataFrame({'a': [1, 1.0, 'a']})
conn.upload({'df': df})
```

Answer (score 0):

Most, if not all of the differences between orca and pandas are due to the differences between DolphinDB and pandas. Here for your case, DolphinDB does not allow mixed data types in a table column. Therefore orca doesn't allow mixed type columns. They explained in section 4.1 of the following tutorial:

https://github.com/dolphindb/Orca/tree/master/totorial_EN

I guess this because DolphinDB aims to be a high-performance database, whereas pandas aims to be able to do anything. They are just different animals.